# How to read text file in folder and display in richTextBox then delete file and read next file placed in same folder

Tags: c#

I want to be able to read a text file in a specific folder and display it in a richTextBox and delete the file once read and keep the content until the new file is placed in that folder.  However what happens now is that it displays the content very briefly and the the app crashes saying that it can't locate the file in that specific folder.

Here is my code I have at the moment:

```
static string path = @"C:\TEST\";
    private FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher;

InitializeComponent();

        fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
        fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        fileSystemWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Changed);
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        RichTextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(path + "event.txt");
        try
        {
            string filename = @"C:\TEST\event.txt";
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Delete(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have made some changes and is working now, but i need it to delete the file.  (At the moment its not deleting it)

```
RichTextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        try
        {
            string filename = @"C:\AMS\event.int";
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                File.Delete(filename);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }
```

Comment: When you run this in debug, does it reach the try statement? What line does it break at?

Comment: Hi, No it it doesn't.  It reaches `richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(path + "event.txt");'

Comment: Is the file definitely there when you're trying to read it? You have code to delete it first, are you sure that that's not deleting it?

Comment: You are checking explicitly for event.txt. That may not be the one triggering change event and a change event might be triggered for different reasons.

Comment: Your File.Delete(filename); is only reached if file does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the fileSystemWatcher_Changed might be called to get to content again from the file, even after the file is gone. Try making sure that this line - 
`richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(path + "event.txt");` is not being called after the file is already deleted - check if the file exists before executing that line. I would also recommend locking two sections of this code-

1) Checking that the file exists and reading from it.

2) Checking that the file exists and deleting it.